# ADT bundle keeps freezing whenever I try to make a project

Tags: android, project, bundle, adt, freeze

The ADT bundle keeps freezing while building a project with the default settings. I am using a mid 2010 Mac Mini with a 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo processor and 8GB of RAM. I am using Mac OS X 10.8.3. I have about 530MB of RAM allocated to Eclipse. Below is a screenshot of the the window, which is unresponsive until I force quit the application.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVWhS.png

Comment: if 64bit, try the 32bit version of eclipse instead of the 64bit.

Comment: There is no 32 bit version of Eclipse that comes in the ADT bundle.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/  you may get it here.  [Adding ADT to eclipse is easy](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)